# How to align text inside a cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a cell containing 2 characters and sometimes 3.
I need to format the cell-like:

```
<2spaces>XX<2spaces>
```

and if contains 3 characters:

```
<2spaces>XXX<1space>.
```

I use a new-style format

```
dx['C'] = dx['C'].map('{:^4s}'.format)
```

Note: dx['C'] is a column in pandas table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given:

```
      C
0   aaa
1    aa
```

Doing:

```
df.C = df.C.str.center(6) if len(df.C)%2 else (' ' + df.C).str.center(6)
```

Output:

```
        C
0    aaa
1    aa
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I need `x` to be left-shifted

Comment: left-shifted? Updated~